# python - what's the difference between "=" and "=="?

Tags: python

I wonder know what's the difference between `a = 1` and `a == a`?
i got two examples as following:

```
a = 2
def test():

        print ("a=", a)
        a == 3

test()
```

and the result :

```
a = 2
```

the other example:

```
a = 2
def test():

        print ("a=", a)
        a = 3

test()
```

and it turned out:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Is there anyone could explain the difference between "=" and "=="?

Comment: `=` is an assignment statement. In your second example `a = 3` creates a local variable called `a` that you are referencing in the local scope before it is assigned. In the first example `a == 3` is an equality expression (no new variable) so it just references the global `a`.

Comment: This question might not be useful as the differences between '=' and '==' are very clearly stated in tutorials

Comment: This is an extremely basic question that could be answered by spending about five minutes with a tutorial. Please do basic research before posting a question.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two are:

- `==` is the operator to check if two objects are equivalent.
- `=` is the operator to assign value(s) to a variable.

**Example:**

```
>>> a = 5 # `=` operator
>>> a
5
>>> a == 5 # `==` operator
True
>>>
```

Also the reason why your code returned an error, is because you already have a variable called `a` outside the function, so there you want to assign it again, it won't work.

**Thanks to @SpencerWieczorek for a much better explanation of the part of explanation below the code:**

> Note: The second example the local a and the global a are entirely different variables. In order to use the global a you defined you would want to add global a at the start of the function. The local variable doesn't have anything to do with the global one and is not the reason for the error.

Comment: *Note:* The second example the local `a` and the global `a` are entirely different variables. In order to use the global `a` you defined you would want to add `global a` at the start of the function. The local variable doesn't have anything to do with the global one.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks so much for the explanation, you know better than me on this one.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Edited mine.

Comment: Assignment statements are one of the first things taught in any programming tutorial.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

To understand the difference between these two you first need to understand the difference between [comparison operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/comparison_operators_example.htm) and [assignment operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/assignment_operators_example.htm)

**`=` assignment operator**

This will assign a given value with another value. There is also `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`... which perform value assignments in place adding, subtracting, multiplying, or dividing the value on the right to the value on the left. *More explanation and information can be found either in the documentation or in the link I provided.

```
a = 5
b = 2
print(a, b)
#5 2
b += 10
print(b)
#12
```

**`==` comparison operator**

This compares two python objects and returns `True` if two variables result in the same value. *(not to be mistaken with `is` which compares if two variables point to the same object)* There's also `!=`, `<>`, `>`, `<`... which determine if two objects results are not equal, greater, or lesser.

```
a == 5
#True
a == b
#False
```

Comment: Assignment statements are one of the first things taught in any programming tutorial.

Comment: Very true, this is why I lamens termed my answer.

Comment: It doesn't need an SO answer with layman's terms; it needs a bare minimum of effort to open a textbook or online tutorial.